# How to use Authorization Token token=A-123456789qwertyuio12 Header in Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2

im trying to consume an api that has that authorization header, i can get a 200 response in Postman with all data but cant get it to work in retrofit

Comment: show your code like what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you need add the `Token` using OkHttp Interceptor.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addNetworkInterceptor(mTokenInterceptor)
        .build();
```

then add it to `Retrofit`:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(client)
        .baseUrl(base_url)
        .build();
```

the `mTokenInterceptor`:

```
Interceptor mTokenInterceptor = new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request request = chain.request();
        if (mToken != null) {
            Request.Builder requestBuilder = request.newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Authorization", mToken);
            Request newRequest = requestBuilder.build();

            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }
        return chain.proceed(request);

    }
};
```

when you get the `Token`, just assign the `mToken`,

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below, just a crude example

```
@GET("your server url goes here")
    Call<Your_Model_Class> getServerData(@Header("Authorization") String token);
```

Pass your token to `getServerData` method.